# z-index Menu lateral (Materialize Css)

Tags: materialize

Estoy realizando el ejercicio de freecodecamp de crear un portfolio. Estoy utilizando Marterialize.css. El problema es el siguiente: cuando debido al tamaño del navegador se activa el menú hamburguesa, el menú se muestra correctamente, pero parece que el menú está situado una capa por debajo que el background gris. He estado toqueteando los z-index, pero incluso asignándoles un index de 999 sigue pareciendo que está abajo. ¿Alguna idea? (os dejo el ejemplo en CodePen)

p.d: el z-index 999 lo he añadido inline en el html, a la classe side-nav

https://codepen.io/subirats345/full/qjLOew

Comment: Deberías crear un [mcve] en la propia pregunta en lugar de poner un enlace externo. De todas formas el `z-index` no te va a servir de nada si los elementos no están al mismo nivel

Comment: Hola @blonfu! Gracias por la respuesta y por el consejo de publicación. Soy nuevo y aún s eme escapan estos detalles. Mira, lo he solucionado poniendo esto:

#sidenav-overlay {
z-index: 996;
}

ACTUALIZAICÓN:

Para no modificar el z-index, mejor mover el side-nav fuera de la etiqueta nav. Funciona perfectamente